# Antlr NoViableAltException

Tags: java, antlr

I have a simple grammar using Antlr 3:

```
grammar i;

@header {
package com.data;
}

null        : 'null';
value       : null | STRING;
elements    : value? | (value ',' value)+;
STRING      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();}; // handle white space between keywords
```

What I am trying to achive is I have a value. So a value can be optional or value follows a comma follwed by another value. So for example:

value could be true or value could be true, true, true, true.

When I do the interpretation the following works:

true

or
true , true

When I trying true, true, true the tree is displayed with true, true but shows a NoViableAltException.

I have also tried:

```
elements: value? | (value ',' value)*;
```

but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

EDIT:

```
insert      : 'INSERT INTO TABLE' 'VALUES' '('elements')'';';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elements` rule is written such that it derives only zero or one value, or any number of pairs that are separated by a comma, with no comma between the pairs.

Apparently what you want is this:

```
elements: ( value ( ',' value )* )?;
```

This allows for nothing at all (due to the `?` operator), or a single value followed by zero or more (`*`) occurrences of a comma and a value.

Comment: One thing it that, I do not want to allow nothing at all. It is either a single value is entered or a value, value. How would this be done?

Comment: Please see edit above in the original description. The insert accepts nothing also.

Comment: Solved, added + instead of ?. Thanks.

Comment: @user1646481, the `?` make `( value ( ',' value )* )` optional. Think about it for a moment how you could allow for minimal 1 value...

Comment: @user1646481, no, `( value ( ',' value )* )+` would also match `value value value` (without comma's). Seeing your recent ANTLR questions, I think it's time to take a step back and learn some ANTLR before continuing.